# UINavigation Swipe Back Gesture use with UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, subview

In my application I am using the standard UIViewController structure around my app. However I have views which I transition to using a UIStoryboardSegue push. In that UIViewController I am doing this in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Then I have this delegate method as well to enable the swipe back gesture:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

**The problem is**, in my original view I presented from, I present a custom menu programmatically in the viewWillAppear using a typical approach like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:menu];
```

This works fine if I were to go back to my main menu using

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However, if I use the swipe back gesture, the view never presents even though the viewWillAppear clearly is called. Is my UINavigationController the issue for this or is something else going on here that I simply do not see?

Comment: I suspect this is the same issue as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503224/ios-app-freezes-on-pushviewcontroller/36637556